# AWS ECS FARGATEがCannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemonでECRのイメージをpullしてくれない

Tags: aws

お世話になっております。

現在AWS上にECS（FARGATE）環境を作成しています。

タスク定義まで終わり、クラスタを作成しデプロしてみたのですが、タイトルにあるとおり以下のエラーでECRのイメージがpull出来ません。

こちら原因としてどのへんを見ていけばよいのでしょうか？
なにか方針などあれば教えていただけると嬉しいです。。。

```
状況の理由 CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://[my repository id].dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
コマンド    ["bundle","exec","rails","server"]

ECRのレポジトリURI
[my repository id].dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/rails
```

Answer (score 1):

以下が参考になるのではないでしょうか。
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_cannot_pull_image.html